# help on simplifying boolean algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I need t show the the terms on the left simplify to the ones on the right
$$(X+Y).(X'+Z)= X.Z+X'.Y$$

---

My attempt:

I went with $$XX'+XZ+YX'+YZ=
             0 +XZ+YX'+YZ$$

But I'm stumped beyond this point, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why can't you do using truth table?

Comment: The question has an error. Your solution is correct.

Comment: Is multiplication on both the sides of equality to be proved allowed for you?

Comment: @Math1000 The solution is correct but not complete; it *can* be simplified to the desired result (by absorption).

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ah, I forgot about that trick, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $YZ = YZ(X+X') \\ = XYZ+X'YZ$

**Hint 2:** Absorption $A+AB = A$

Comment: so I will be unable to get exactly X.Z+X′.Y I believe ?

Comment: @boolean_n Why would you believe that?  $A+AB~=~A(1+B) \\ ~~= ~A$

Comment: thanks for the help, I'm still new to this stuff

Comment: @boolean_n Stick with it. $~$ It gets easier when you become familiar with the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

In boolean algebra if $A=B$ then $AC=BC$ 
Now let's consider your equation $$(X+Y).(X'+Z)=XZ+YX'+YZ \tag{1.}$$
this has to be proved equal to $$XZ+X'Y \tag{2.}$$ 
Now multiply both eq (1.) and (2.) by $Z'$ you will get both equal to $X'YZ'$